# Adding child element to a parent element using javascript

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I am trying to add a **child element** to a **parent element** as follows:

- `li` to be added to `ul`
- Either when the enter button is clicked or the enter key on the keyboard is pressed, a new `li` and **delete** button should get added to `ul`.

My code isn't working right. Can someone help me with this, please?

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Simple Add/Remove Task</h1>
<h2>To do List</h2>

<input type="text" placeholder="enter your tasks" id="userInput">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>
<ul>
  <li class="todos">Wake up <button>Delete</button></li>
  <li class="todos">Study<button>Delete</button></li> 
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".todos");
var input = document.getElementById("userInput");
var ul = document.querySelectorAll("ul");
var button = document.getElementById("enter");

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(input.value.length>0){
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
  }
});

input.addEventListener("keypress", function(){
  if(input.value.length > 0 && event.which === 13){
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
  }
});

for (var i = 0; i<listItems.length; i++){
  listItems[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.classList.toggle("done");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySelectorAll` returns NodeList. NodeList does not contain appendChild method. So either try to replace `ul.appendChild` with `ul[0].appendChild` or just refactor your code

Answer (score 2):

This solution modifies your item-adding code **to include a delete button** (and refactors the code into a dedicated function.)

All delete buttons (**marked with a "delete-btn" class**) trigger list-item removal. (The click event bubbles up to the ul, where the listener is attached.)

See the in-code comments for further explanation.

```js
// Identifies DOM elements
const
  listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".todos"),
  input = document.getElementById("userInput"),
  ul = document.getElementById("the-list"), // (NOT `querySelectorAll`)
  button = document.getElementById("enter");

// Conditionally calls addItem function when button is clicked
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (input.value.length > 0) {
    addItem();
  }
});

// Conditionally calls addItem function when ENTER is pressed
input.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
  if (input.value.length > 0 && event.which === 13){
    addItem();
  }
});

// Adds an item to the list (when called by either listener)
function addItem(){
  const
    li = document.createElement("li"),
    txt = document.createTextNode(input.value),
    btn = document.createElement("button");
  // Puts txt & btn inside li
  li.appendChild(txt);
  btn.textContent = "Delete";
  btn.classList.add("delete-btn"); // For later reference
  li.appendChild(btn);  

  ul.appendChild(li); // Puts li inside ul
  input.value = ""; // Clears input
}

// Listens for clicks on the `ul` or its descendants, even if the
//   clicked element gets dynamically added later
ul.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  // Listeners can automatically access triggering events
  const clickedElement = event.target; // Events have a target property
  if(clickedElement.classList.contains("delete-btn")){
    // Finds ancestor elements and removes li from ul
    const
      li = clickedElement.closest("li"),
      ul = li.closest("ul");
    ul.removeChild(li); // (Or we could add "done" to li's classList)
  }
});
```

```css
.delete-btn{
  margin-left: 1em;
}

/*
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
*/
```

```html
<h1>Simple Add/Remove Task</h1>
<h2>To do List</h2>

<input type="text" placeholder="enter your tasks" id="userInput">
<button id="enter">Enter</button>

<ul id="the-list">
  <li class="todos">Wake up<button class="delete-btn">Delete</button></li>
  <li class="todos">Study<button class="delete-btn">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: a bit frustrated right now. Can you point me towards a good source for learning Dom manipulation? I will try this code and thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, MDN is many people's #1 source for a lot of Web-development info. Their intro to DOM manipulation seems like a great place to start: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

`var ul = document.querySelectorAll("ul");`

to this,

`var ul = document.querySelector("ul");`

As you have only one `ul` in your html.