# Trouble creating a delete button for my project

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently making a program for my players in an RPG to be able to select their characters skills from drop down menus which will 1. Display the title of the skill under the results section and also in the Selected Advantages section(top right). 2. Display the description of the skill under its title.

I have been able to achieve this and now I want the User to be able to click on the button next to each listed skill in the Selected Advantages section and have that delete all entries for that skill. I have spent hours trying to figure this out but have only been able to delete all entries and not just the desired one.

I have tried using remove() and removeChild, assigning the new divs ID's and many other attempts but never get it quite working. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```js
let placeText = document.getElementById('place-text');
let selectedText = document.getElementById('selected-items');

//AAAAAAAAAA
document.getElementById("submit-advantage-a").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let userAdvantageA = document.getElementById('user-advantages-a').value;
  let title = document.createElement('p');
  let hr = document.createElement('hr');
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  
  if (userAdvantageA === 'absolute direction') {
    placeText.append(hr);
    placeText.append(title);
    title.innerText = 'Absolute Direction';
    placeText.innerHTML += Object.values(absoluteDirection);
    selected.append('Absolute Direction');
    selected.appendChild(button); 
    selected.append(hr);
  } else if (userAdvantageA === 'absolute timing') {
    placeText.append(hr);
    placeText.append(title);
    title.innerText = 'Absolute Timing';
    placeText.innerHTML += Object.values(absoluteTiming);
    selectedText.append('Absolute Timing');
    selectedText.append(button);
    selectedText.append(hr);
  } else if (userAdvantageA === 'acute senses') {
    placeText.append(hr);
    placeText.append(title);
    title.innerText = 'Acute Senses';
    placeText.innerHTML += Object.values(acuteSenses);
    selectedText.append('Acute Senses');
    selectedText.append(button);
    selectedText.append(hr);
  } 
  });

//............A
let absoluteDirection = {
  absoluteDirection: "Texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext",
};

let absoluteTiming = {
  absoluteTiming: "Texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext"
};

let acuteSenses = {
 description: 'Texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext'
};
```

```css
#place-text p {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: large;
  }

  #selected {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    text-align: center;   
    width: 20%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="GCRC.css"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>GCRC test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="/GCRC.html">Home</a>
  <div id="selected"><strong>SELECTED ADVANTAGES</strong><hr>
    <div id="selected-items"></div>
  </div>
  <header>
    <h1>Advantages</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h3>A.</h3>
    <form method="GET">
      <select name="user-advantages-a" id="user-advantages-a">
        <option value="absolute direction">Absolute Direction</option>
        <option value="absolute timing">Absolute Timing</option>
        <option value="acute senses">Acute Senses</option>
      </select>
      <input id="submit-advantage-a" type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <h1>Results</h1>
    <advantages>
      <div id="place-text"></div>
    </advantages>
  </main>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="GCRC.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not exactly the same, but check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62888638/8223070. The trick to listening for clicks on a dynamically added delete button is 1) to add your listener to some element that you know is always present in the DOM (the `ul` in the case of that example), 2) to get the `event.target` in the  listener so you know which element was actually clicked, and 3) to use the `.closest()` method (or the .parentElement property) to move up the DOM tree to whichever ancestor element needs to be deleted.

Comment: #selected-items button - this is for delete?